# Why can't I check if there is a number in a list?

Tags: python

When I tried checking if a number was in a list, it came up with an error in the console. Here is the code.

```
player_turn = True
player_score = 0
enemy_score = 0
rolls_list = []
tempScore = 0

if player_turn:
    user_input = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? (0 - 10)"))
    for i in range(user_input):
        rolls_list = random.randint(1,6)
        print(rolls_list)
        tempScore += rolls_list
    if 1 in rolls_list:
        tempScore = 1
    player_score = tempScore
```

I tried moving the if statement in and out of the for loop but it popped up the same result.

Comment: Typo.  Instead of `rolls_list =`, you want `rolls_list.append( ... )`.  As soon as you do one loop, `rolls_list` is not a list any more.

Comment: _it came up with an error in the console_ Are we supposed to guess what the error was?

Answer (score 1):

On each loop iteration you are assigning a random number to `rolls_list`. Thus when you check for membership in `rolls_list` later, it's just an int and not a list.

Instead you want to *append* to the list. You also probably want to assign the "roll" to a variable so you can work with it in multiple places within the loop iteration.

```
if player_turn:
    user_input = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? (0 - 10)"))
    for i in range(user_input):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        rolls_list.append(roll)
        print(roll)
        tempScore += roll
    if 1 in rolls_list:
        tempScore = 1
    player_score = tempScore
```